# Nextjs routing case sensitivity for catch-all routing segment

Tags: next.js

I am not sure whether this is a bug that should be reported or simple configuration issue of the routing.

We have a file structure `/Segment/[dynamic-slug].js` which behaves same way with URL.
When we try to access it with "/Segment/something.js" it works as expexted, but when the request is "/segment/something.js" it returns 404.

For other routes without nesting, both cases work and return the result.

The permanent redirect option in `next.config.js` ends up in an endless loop, when trying to redirect from `/segment/:slug` to `/Segment/:slug`...

Behavior is strange, so has anyone come across something like that?